# overlaying marks in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to set up the color strength of the marks in pgfplots, so that you can see how many marks have the same coordinates?

For example: If I have got the point `(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 4)` than of course pgfplots only shows the points `(1, 2), (3, 4)`. Is it possible, to get the point `(1, 2)` in (for example) light blue and the point `(3, 4)` in dark blue?

I guess, this can be done manually, but I want to automate this as much, as possible.

So pgfplots should look up, which point occurs most (here `(3, 4)`), set it's color strength to 100%, calculate the color strength of a single occurrence (here 50%).

### Example 2:

points: `(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (-2, -2), (-2, -2), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5)`

**color strength:**

`(1, 1)`: 20%

`(2, 2)` and `(-2, -2)`: 40%

`(5, 5)`: 100%

Code to play with:

```
\documentclass[preview, border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two
 1   1
 2   2
 2   2
-2  -2
-2  -2
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=one, y=two, only marks] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer sets up some classes for visualizing the points. The method is described on p113 of the `pgfplots` manual v1.15 (2017/06/05).

Each point has a class label attached. The classes are:

- Class a: (1, 1) - set at an opacity of 20%;
- Class b: (2, 2) and (-2, -2) - set at an opacity of 40%; and
- Class c: (5, 5) - set an opacity of 100%

The class labels are appended as meta data to the data values. In this case, where the data are supplied as a table, each row becomes    e.g. 5 5 1, where the x value is 5, the y value is 5 and the opacity is 1. Note that if the data are supplied as coordinates, the syntax are: (x-value,y-value) [opacity value].

The scatter classes are defined as an axis option using:

```
scatter/classes={
    a={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.2},
    b={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.4},
    c={mark=*,blue,opacity=1.0} 
}
```

This provides for customizing the marks, not just with opacity, but also colours, shapes, mark size, rotations etc.

The `\addplot` includes the option `scatter src=explicit symbolic` which informs the plot to use the meta data.

There are four examples. Ex 1 is the result for the solution posted by Torbjørn.

Ex 2 uses classes to modify opacity.

Ex 3 uses classes to modify shape and colour.

Ex 4 combines the use of opacity, mark size and labels to identify the number of points at each co-ordinate. The number of values at each co-ordinate is added using a `node` with a `pin`. This provides the ability to explicitly indicate the number of values at each point.

Note the colour difference between Ex 1 and Ex 2, but I don't know which would be regarded as "correct". If the intention is to create a visual difference by modifying opacity, both Ex 1 and Ex 2 serve that purpose.

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two opacity
 1   1 a
 2   2 b
 2   2 b
-2  -2 b
-2  -2 b
 5   5 c
 5   5 c 
 5   5 c
 5   5 c
 5   5 c
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Ex 1,
height=6cm,
width=6cm,
%legend
]
\addplot [
only marks,
mark size=6pt,
mark options={opacity=0.2,blue},
] table [x=one, y=two] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Ex 2,
height=6cm,
width=6cm,
scatter/classes={
    a={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.2},
    b={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.4},
    c={mark=*,blue,opacity=1.0} 
}
]
\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
mark size=6pt,
scatter src=explicit symbolic
]
 table [x=one,y=two,meta=opacity] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Ex 3,
height=6cm,
width=6cm,
scatter/classes={
    a={mark=*,magenta,opacity=1.0},
    b={mark=triangle*,cyan,opacity=1.0},
    c={mark=square*,orange,opacity=1.0} 
}
]
\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
mark size=6pt,
scatter src=explicit symbolic
]
table [x=one,y=two,meta=opacity] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Ex 4,
height=6cm,
width=6cm,
scatter/classes={
    a={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.2,mark size=2},
    b={mark=*,blue,opacity=0.4,mark size=4},
    c={mark=*,blue,opacity=1.0,mark size=6} 
}
]
\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
mark size=6pt,
scatter src=explicit symbolic,
]
table [x=one,y=two,meta=opacity] {datatable.txt}
node [pin={[pin distance=0.35cm,pin edge={<-,shorten <=3pt,thick}]right:1},pos=0] {}   % pos=0 -> First value in table
node [pin={[pin distance=0.35cm,pin edge={<-,shorten <=3pt,thick}]right:2},pos=0.2] {} % There are 10 data points. There are 2 points at (2,2). The first (2,2) value is in the 2/10 position so pos=0.2
node [pin={[pin distance=0.35cm,pin edge={<-,shorten <=4pt,thick}]right:2},pos=0.4] {} % The 4/10 position
node [pin={[pin distance=0.35cm,pin edge={<-,shorten <=4pt,thick}]left:5},pos=1] {}    % pos=1 -> last value in table
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found this solution too. Since one is able to calculate the quantity, this solution works well

Comment: I thing you should delete `height=6cm, width=6cm` from the `addplot`-part in the second example, shouldn't you?

Comment: I don't know if this is very helpful, but one can 'name' the classes by numbers. Here instead on `a, b, c` I would use `1, 2, 5` and name the column `count`

Comment: Yes that works. It is providing a different labelling nomenclature. Just add a column count and change `meta=opacity` to `meta=count` and replace a, b and c in `scatter/classes` with 1, 2,3. This opens the way for using `visualization depends on=\thisrow{count} as \marksize`, for example.

Comment: That is, what I tried to point out ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps reduce the opacity of the marks.

Note: don't add plot options in the brackets that come after `table`, do `\addplot [<plot options>] table[<table options>] {<table>};`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[preview, border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two
 1   1
 2   2
 2   2
-2  -2
-2  -2
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
 5   5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks,mark options={opacity=0.2,blue}] table [x=one, y=two] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the note. It surely doesn't compute 0.2 on it's on, but this isn't the main feature. I thought, that there would be a build-in-funktion

Comment: @Ben I don't think there is anything built-in. It's likely possible, but I would think it needs a bit more work than this quick hack.

Comment: I meant `opacity`. But I've got a question: Why isn't the point `(5, 5)` as dark blue as it was without the `opacity`-option? I feel like, the values `0.2` aren't added up right

Comment: @Ben That's a color blending question that I can't answer authoritatively, but it's not just adding the opacity values. Say you have two dots of 50% opacity. That means 50% of the white background shows through the first dot. Then 50% of that again will show through the second one, so you end up with 25% of the background showing through both. Try `\fill [blue] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\fill [blue,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\fill [blue,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\fill [blue,opacity=0.75] (2,0) rectangle +(1,1);`

Comment: My fault. I think that this solution is an easy way, but because of this fact it isn't very nice. In my example the point (5, 5) has an opacity of `1-(1-1/5)^5=0.67`. The other points with opacity in {1, 2, 3, 4} have: 0.2, 0.36, 0.488, 0.59 so you can't see the difference really good, because it doesn't use the hole range. If you have got more than five (lets say `n`) identical points the maximum would be `1-(1-1/n)^n=(e-1)/e=0.63` for large `n`